# sudo to any user without a password

Tags: linux, passwords, sudo, sudoers

If sudo can be configured to no password such as:

```
bob ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then how can you configure sudo to be able to sudo to any user without password ?

So that

```
sudo -u domainnameuser.com mkdir www
```

Works for the sudo user without prompting for a [sudo] password ?

Is it possible to allow this without explicitly enabling it for each user in /etc/sudoers.d and just allow switching to all users and using all commands ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a rule as such:

```
ALL ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir www ""
```

This reads something like: "Allow any user on any domain to act as any user:group without asking for a password to execute the exact command "mkdir www" (using only `/bin/mkdir`, and not some other `mkdir`). The ending set of quotes tells `sudo` not to allow any further arguments.

(Rules are determined in order with the last matching rule taking effect. If you have another rule after this one that would cover the same command (such as ALL) it would take effect instead. I had a problem in my own config where I was specifying `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` afterwards. Since this rule matches the situation, but requires a password, a password was being asked.)

Really this isn't the way to do something like this. Parts of your description imply that you have things setup in a bizarre way. I won't get into that as it's out of scope but, to accomplish what you want and more flexibility, there may be a better way. It seems you want to let users create sub-directories with a specific name owned by the owner of the parent directory. Instead, create a script that does what you want (looks up current directory, determines its owner and group, creates a directory `www` here, `chmod` the new directory to the determined user and group.), and have the script allowed as run-able by root without password in the `sudo` config. Doing it this way means that the user only has to navigate to the directory then `sudo create-www` or whatever. You'll also be able to configure other rules in the script such as ones only allowing `www` to be created in certain directories.

Comment: Isn't this the opposite? Sudo FROM any user? I can see why you recognize that as a problem :) The problem is here that the password is required when "sudo -u anyuser" is used to perform a mkdir on that user to retain permissions for the specific user in that directory (as given, a /home example in a shared webhosting)

Comment: @dezza I misunderstood the question. I'll see about updating or deleting my answer.

Comment: If you have any thoughts on the security and why the design discourages this apparently just leave your thoughts :)

Comment: @dezza Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I setup a non-root user with the base image of `ubuntu:18.04`:

```
RUN \
    groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' && \
    sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' && \
    echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers && \
    echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" && \
    echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```

What happens with the above code:

- The user and group `foo` is created.
- The user `foo` is added to the both the `foo` and `sudo` group.
- The `uid` and `gid` is set to the value of `999`.
- The home directory is set to `/home/foo`.
- The shell is set to `/bin/bash`.
- The `sed` command does inline updates to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow `foo` and `root` users passwordless access to the `sudo` group.
- The `sed` command disables the `#includedir` directive that would allow any files in subdirectories to override these inline updates.

This can be done non-interactively if you don't need it for Docker by removing the trailing slashes after the `&&` commands:

```bsh
groupadd -g 999 foo && useradd -u 999 -g foo -G sudo -m -s /bin/bash foo &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^%sudo.*/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^root.*/root ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/g' &&
sed -i /etc/sudoers -re 's/^#includedir.*/## **Removed the include directive** ##"/g' &&
echo "foo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers &&
echo "Customized the sudoers file for passwordless access to the foo user!" &&
echo "foo user:";  su - foo -c id
```